# How to trigger an event on a <select> element when the same value is selected?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select, addeventlistener, eventtrigger

The event type change will be triggered when a different item is selected from the combo box, but won't be triggered when the same item is selected again. What other event type or trick/loophole will get me the desired action?

```js
const options = document.querySelector('#select');
options.addEventListener('change', function() { // won't be triggered when chosen the item chosen is the same
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option value="1" selected>1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Default and expected behaviour of a select, is the change event triggering when you CHANGE the select. If you just look at the options and choose the same option that was already selected, then no event is expected. So if you need to trigger each time, then you need to use the use click

In any case add a "Please select" to allow the event to trigger on the first actual options

```js
document.querySelector('#select').addEventListener('click', function() { 
  if (this.value) console.log(this.value); 
});
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option value="" selected>Please select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The action will be triggered when I click on the ComboBox itself, not the items within which is weird behavior. I want the action to be triggered upon selection of a particular item not when clicking the ComboBox.

Comment: Your need to trigger the option again when selected again is the weird thing. We normally only expect this to happen on change as you had it. So no other event than the click event is triggered when clicking the same option again